# Update Firebase Array using.where(). But, getting error ".update isn't a function

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

So, I am trying to update a document in my firebase that has an array.

Currently, a users document may look like this.

username : John
postedProjects : ['project-one','project-two']

However, as John submits "project-three" to another collection, I want to grab johns document, and add "project-three" into his array.

> Here is my code currently (Please note, I am not using the document
>   UID as I have set UID as name, but the user may change their username
>   down the line, but their UID remains the same)

```
  var newProject = db.collection('users').where('user_id', '==', this.userInfo.user_id);
  newProject.update({
    postedProjects: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion("test")
  })
```

This is the code I have followed from the [Firebase doc](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array), with the slight adjustment of changing .doc(uid) to .where, to instead match the existing user to the one on the collection.

However, I get an error stating "newProject.update is not a function".

-- Added .where but still getting error as i am not sure where to put the "update()"

```
        db.collection('users').where('user_id', '==', this.userInfo.user_id)
      .get()
      .then(function(querySnapshot)  {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {

        doc.data().update({
          postedProjects: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion("new project")
        })
      })
    })}}
```

Comment: Firestore doesn't support update queries, where you send a query and update statement to the server. Instead, you'll have to execute the query, retrieve the results, and then update them individually.

Answer (score 1):

[where()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#where) returns a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query) object, which doesn't have an `update()` method, as you can see from the linked API documentation.  Since there is no guarantee how many documents could result from [executing a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query), you will have to [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#get) the query, then iterate the results to find a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) that matches document, use its [ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#ref) property to get a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.html) for it, and finally `update()` the document using that DocumentReference.

Comment: I updated my code to what i figured would work, but i am still missed something or not understanding where "update()" needs to go.